# how to send a json to the server with Typescript

Tags: typescript

In ASP, the single page application Vue.js template uses `fetch` to get the data from the server. This is an example provided by Microsoft, using Typescript:

```
fetch('your/api/route/')
    .then(response => response.json() as Promise<MyObj[]>)
    .then(data => {
        this.objs = data;
    });
```

I am trying to find the reverse function to send the data to the server (without having to use Axios or any other third party library).

I am assuming that if `fetch` is provided by default, the reverse functionality must also be available.

---

This is the `fetch` function declaration:

```
declare function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;
```

Declaration found in the file: `%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.5\lib.d.ts`

---

Googling the keywords "typescript post json" or "typescript send json" doesn't seem to provide any meaningful results.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where your typescript/Javascript is running.
In the browser the fetch API is the way to go:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

In NodeJS you can use the http API :https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback